# USB hard drive not recognized while pc is running

Tags: windows-10, usb

I've had a strange, reproduceable phenomenon for a few weeks. If I plug in a specific USB hard drive it is not recognized, regardless of how many times I unplug and replug it. An error is even shown that a device can't be recognized. But if I plug it in before I start the PC, then the drive is normally recognized with no problem. For programs that use ports I could think of a specific port being already used. But as this is a USB device, something like that shouldn't be possible (as far as I'm aware).

So my question is here (generally, not specific to this HD): In such cases that a USB device can only be recognized if plugged in before starting the PC, what could be the reason for something like that?

Update:

- Windows version: 10.0.17134 build 17134
- HD: Seagate Backup + Hub BK SCSI Disk Device
- I would say USB 2 Driver: 21.06.2006  v: 10.0.17134.1

Comment: Tried unplugging all other USB devices, then connecting the hard drive in question? Maybe there's a conflict... And what's the exact error shown when "a device can't be recognized"?

Comment: I had just the opposite case: USB 3.0 disk not recognized if plugged-in before the boot. This lasted years before it disappeared one day with an update of Windows and perhaps also the driver. We need to know your hardware and Windows 10 version, and for which USB type this is happening (2.x or 3.x). My driver in question was [Intel® USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/65855/Intel-USB-3-0-eXtensible-Host-Controller-Driver).

Comment: @Xen2050 that was the first thing I tried, but to no avail

Comment: @harrymc I have a similar problem under windows 7+ on my laptop.....even more extreme as it stops booting alltogether if specific hard drives are connected to it during the bootup sequence (first transition from bios to os stops then the os start stops).  When I unplug it continues normally...also normal handling if plugged in after start :)

Comment: for driver details and usb type I will check as soon as I get home today and edit the question and highlight you again

Comment: @harrymc updated

Comment: Is this a home built computer or from a store?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers back in its time it was a windows 8 store computer (the usb hdd is an external backup hdd, as I'm creating software I use it as additional backup for created data mostly,...) nad got upgraded via the option

Comment: I just suspect power issues but less likely with off the shelf computer

Comment: I would debug same steps with a LiveISO booting from RAM

Answer (score 4):

Many kinds of problems can arrive with USB devices, and there are many solutions.
I have tried to compile below the solutions I know of in Windows 10.

1. Run the USB troubleshooter of Windows.
2. Since Windows 10 was an upgrade from Windows 8, deleting the USB Controllers
   devices in Device Manager and reboot will force the usage of Windows 10 drivers.
   See the next point.
3. Device manager may not show all the devices it knows about.
   To ensure seeing all of them, start it in a Command Prompt run as Administrator
   and enter the following commands:

   ```
   set DEVMGR_SHOW_DETAILS=1
   set DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1
   start devmgmt.msc
   ```
4. Use the free [USB Oblivion](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usboblivion/)
   to wipe out all traces of the USB drivers and reboot.
5. Search for a driver for your USB Controller on the manufacturer's website.
6. Try a different USB cable.
7. Check for a BIOS update (carefully!).
8. Try using a different USB port. If the computer has back and front ports,
   and some are working better, this can be a power supply problem where the
   ports are not getting enough power. Some ports may have a shared feed from
   the power supply with too many USB devices on this one feed.
9. In Device Manager, right-click the USB Controller, choose Properties,
   and in the Power Management tab uncheck
   *Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power* and click OK.
10. [Disable fast startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html).
11. In *Control Panel > Power Options > Change plan settings >
    Change advanced power settings > USB settings > USB selective suspend settings*,
    disable both *On battery* and *Plugged in* settings.
12. If you don't have USB3 devices, then disable USB3 support from BIOS.
13. Disable your anti-virus if it is not Windows Defender.
14. Update your chipset driver if you can find a later version.
15. Reinstall Windows from scratch.

Before starting all this, ensure your backups are good and create a
system restore point.

Comment: "Since Windows 10 was an upgrade from Windows 10" -> Did you mean 7 or 8?

Comment: @K.A: I meant "from Windows 8". Thanks.

Comment: I would do BIOS update and then chipset driver for your motherboard first.

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting USB hard drive to a PC, it's recognized by the PC (before the OS) that's an hard drive. And the PC will treat it like any hard drive. That is permitting booting on for example.

Search for a setting in your BIOS that's not allowing hot plug of hard drive. That's may be the problem here. Your operating system is certainly innocent.

Comment: I suspect the OS primarily because it started only 2 weeks ago and no problem before that (so I dont think the bios is a possibility in this case...other cases possible but in this most probably noit()

Comment: Fresh install? Well, some moyherboards needs a driver to use storage properly, at startup, mount is handled by bios, but once os started, this driver have to do something to use the new storage. This kind of driver enable better optimisation for disc usage, bit if not installed, run crazy. Have you checked the existence of this kind of driver and installed it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking through your BIOS or UEFI setup to enable hot-plugging. However, I have seen this problem with many USB flash drives of mine, and I know the cause of it. If you burn an ISO using a utility like Rufus on Windows or a raw file/data manipulator like Linux's dd, you will not be able to see the partition from any operating system because the filesystem type would be iso9660, rather than something recognizable from Windows (i.e. NTFS, FAT32, exFAT) or even from Linux distros/MacOS (HFS+, APFS, ext4, btrfs, ReiserFS). However, firmware or partitioning software like GParted or Diskpart would recognize it and simply not mount it if it is hot-plugged. Try formatting the drive after moving your files to an external storage device that works with something like FAT32 (readable across most, if not all, OSes), and moving your files back. This should solve your problem.